# Camel + Velocity: how to put things in Velocity context

Tags: java, apache-camel, velocity

I have a lot of velocity templates that can be reused for another project (which is using Camel).

[Reading the documentation](http://camel.apache.org/velocity.html) I'm not able to understand how to insert some custom object in the velocity context...my templates are expecting two or three different tools; I see that I can set those objects in the header but in this way I have to change my templates, and of course I would avoid that.

So basically in my template I have something like

```
$xpath.blablabla
$anotherTool.doSomething
```

Previously (in the other project) I set up those objects in a java class, now I could create a processor for doing the entire velocity processing but I suppose there's a quick way to avoid coding.

Comment: I have only done it that way, where you run the processor first (setting the headers for all the content you need) and then call `to("velocity:mytemplate.vm")` subsequently. I'm not sure if there's a different way, but that way sure works fine for me.

Comment: I didn't get the point...if you use a processor then all velocity work will be put there...how can you (in a processor) create a velocityContext, fill that with your objects and then pass that velocity context to velocity:mytemplate endpoint? I see in the VelocityEndpoint source code a new VelocityContext instance is created

Comment: In my example I put the relevant values into the headers on the camel `Exchange`. So my `Processor` does `exchange.getIn().setHeader("abc", "123")` ...there must be some magic in the camel-velocity component that makes the camel headers available as `${header.abc}` in the velocity context.

Comment: Ok, my problem is that in my templates I have ${abc} and not ${header.abc}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can add message header to tell camel velocity endpoint to load a VelocityContext there. In this way, user can override the old behavior of camel velocity endpoint. I just fill a JIRA [CAMEL-7532](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7532) for it.